# using session in wordpress to get template only once

Tags: php, wordpress, session, isset

Hi I am using session in wordpress to get template part in the session. I am new to php and don't know how to fix.

Using below code to pull the template part once and use only the first one for the session. 
It pulls only once but when I refresh the page it returns blank 
How can I fix it?

```
            <!-- Main file -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['function_ran'])){ 
                        get_template_part( 'parts/template-part' );
                    $_SESSION['function_ran'] = true; 
                    }  
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- Main file -->

            Below is the template part im am trying to pull only once during the session

            [ parts/template-part ]

            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="fgfgfg">


            </div>
            </div>
```

further added the code in function.php

```
            function register_my_session()
            {
            if( !session_id() )
            {
            session_start();
            }
            }

            add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Comment: please provide more detail and code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that Wordpress doesn't run any `session_start();`, You need to call it on your `functions.php` if you use $_SESSION variable.

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
```